# Find & Set cursor position in contenteditable div using Rangy library

Tags: javascript, jquery, rangy

I just downloaded the popular `Rangy library`. I have the following html

```
<div id="myEditor" contenteditable="true"></div>
<button>Submit</button>
```

This is my jquery code

```
$("button").on("click",function(){ var caretPosition = * how to do it; console.log(caretPosition); });
```

Comment: What is the question?